# How to run converted .asm code from .c using 'gcc' in Emu8086

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, emu8086, converters

I am new here and I converted code from C language to asm. However, it doesn't look like normal code in asm language. So my question is how can I convert a code from C(or C++) language to Assembly language, that the converted asm code could be run on Emu8086.

Here is a simple c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Hello(){
printf("Hello world");
}
int main (){
Hello();
return 0;
}
```

Then I converted it with `gcc -S test.c` and here is the answer:

```
.file   "test1.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world"
    .text
    .globl  Hello
    .type   Hello, @function
Hello:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   Hello, .-Hello
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    Hello
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: That is 64 bit code. You will never get that running in emu8086. You could use a 16 bit compiler but even then, you don't have the standard library so you should avoid using functions such as `printf`. Of course the actual assembly syntax will probably need adjustment too. You can however run that in gdb natively (depending on what you want to achieve).

Comment: that will not work.. not only because of different syntax, but because you did use 64 bit gcc (targetting x86-64 mode), which is like different CPU. Although each modern x86 CPU can handle three major different modes (16 bit real mode, 32 bit mode, and 64 bit mode), they are sort of like three different machines, and when you want to run particular target, you have to switch that mode. `emu8086` does emulate only 16 bit real mode (although extended by 32 bit registers I think, like 80386 CPU), but it can't run 32 bit or 64 bit mode code. You would need C compiler for "x86-16", like watcom/etc.

Comment: *"I converted code from C language to asm"* - no, you didn't. Compiler did. You just invoked the compiler. The difference is like you would take an Aspirin pill and suddenly claim that you invented a cure... ... it will take quite some more effort, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

Emu8086 does what it says on the tin: it emulates an Intel 8086 processor. The assembly that GCC has produced is for your host machine (since you haven't told it to do otherwise), which evidently uses an x86-64 instructions set. The 8086 can't understand most of these instructions. You need to cross-compile it to an x86 16-bit real-mode executable. The `-m16` option on GCC will generate 16-bit code, but it apparently still uses 32-bit registers (EAX, etc.). So you will have to find a compiler that targets the basic 8086 instruction set.

Comment: Regardless of options GCC does not support 8086. The -m16 options produces code that uses 32 bit registers.

Comment: Not only the instruction set is wrong, but the output is also for GNU `as` (so, AT&T syntax and all those directives starting with a dot) and targeting a Linux machine with glibc (`printf`, that particular calling convention).

Comment: As far as the AT&T versus Intel syntax, that shouldn't be a problem, it will still assemble to the same machine code. And `-masm=intel` can fix it anyway.